# Animating two rotating circles

Tags: graphics, dynamic, animation

I have two circles:

```
dottedCircle1[{x_, y_}, angle_, rad_] := {Circle[{x, y}, rad], 
Line[{{x, y}, rad {Sin[angle], Cos[angle]} + {x, y}}],
PointSize[0.03], RGBColor[1, 0, 0],
Point[rad {Sin[angle], Cos[angle]} + {x, y}]}

dottedCircle2[{x_, y_}, angle_, rad_] := {Circle[{x, y}, rad], 
Line[{{x, y}, rad {Sin[angle], Cos[angle]} + {x, y}}],
PointSize[0.03], RGBColor[2, 2, 0],
Point[rad {Sin[angle], Cos[angle]} + {x, y}]}

Show[Graphics[dottedCircle1[{0, 0}, Pi, 1]], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

and I want them spinning with some specific speeds.

First one should rotating with constant speed f0 and the second one should starts to rotate by rubbing the first one (f1=f0 r/R (1-exp(t/T))).

Does anyone know at least how to make them show together (side by side) and spin?

Comment: have you read the documentation of `Dynamic`? [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Show[Graphics[dottedCircle1[{0, 0}, Pi/2 + a, R]], 
   Graphics[dottedCircle2[{R + r, 0}, -Pi/2 + s a, r]], AspectRatio -> Automatic], 
  {a, 0, 2 Pi}, {{R, 1}, 0, 10}, {{r, .5}, 0, 10}, {{s, 0}, 0, 10, 1}]
```

[image]